# When do some strings are not created via string const pool in java?

Tags: java, string

I want to clarify a doubt here

when we create a string via new operator

```
String s=new String("jk");
```

jk goes in String constant pool and heap

Now see

```
String s1=s+"winter"; 
 //case1
```

or

```
String s1="jk"+new String("winter");
```

Does winter in both case go to String Const pool?

How do i check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In both cases `"winter"` will go into the String constants pool. The JLS specifies that anything between `""` is considered as a *compile-time constant* and goes into the String constants pool.

Note : `new String("winter")` --> is redundant and almost always considered *evil*

Comment: I think in second case it will not becoz via new operator winter is created[which thus is created at runtime] as told by @Thomas Stets

Comment: @mansikbchawla - No. Like I said - anything between `""` goes into the String constants pool. It is a *compile time resolution*

Comment: @mansikbchawla - In the second case, you will have `jkwinter` on the heap but `"jk"` and `"winter"` as 2 *separate Strings* in the Strings constants pool

Comment: @lostmind Okay i am getting confused between your answer and Thomas as wether winter will be created in StringConstPool or not?How can i check whether winter is created in StringConstant pool or not

Comment: @TheLostMind thank you very much for explanation,you are the best,deserve a plus 1

Comment: @mansikbchawla - There is a line in the generated class file - `13: ldc           #25                 // String winter`. This means the *compiler* has already parsed the file and has recognized `"winter"` as a String literal and will add it to the String constants pool

Comment: @lostmind U are right ,Thomas Stets has done a mistake in his answer by treating winter as a regular Object

Comment: @mansikbchawla - You could look at the byte-code of your java code check :)

Answer (score 1):

Only String constants like `"abc"`, or expressions that the compiler can evaluate during compile-time, like `"abc" + "def"`, or strings that you call `intern()` on go into the constant pool.

Strings that result from an expression evaluated during runtime are just regular objects.

Comment: Okay Conclusion In case1 here winter goes in StringConstPool where as in case 2 it isn't?

Comment: can you explain a bit more I thought doing `new String("winter");` will reuse `"winter"` from pool(if present)

Comment: @deogratias - No. It will create a new Object on the heap *irrespective* of whether `"winter"` is present on the *constants pool* or not. (it will add `"winter"` to the constants pool if it is not already present.

Comment: @TheLostMind does it means we should avoid using `new String()` as its doing 2 operations adding to heap and adding to pool

Comment: @deogratias - Yes. `new String("abc")`; is almost always redundant.

Comment: @Thomas Stets Ur Suggestion please?